# Search and replace string in unix bash

Tags: regex, bash, replace

I'm not very good on regex, I need to search for

`<`anyword`/>`  and repace with `<anyword></anyword>`

Like `<book/>` to `<book></book>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to parse XML with regexes, which is usually a bad idea — XML is much more complicated than it may initially seem (what happens when you need to replace `<a b="c"/>` with `<a b="c"></a>`? what about non-ASCII element names?) — but if you're certain that what you've described is exactly what you need, then you can write:

```
perl -pe 's{<(\w+)/>}{<$1></$1>}g' < input_file > output_file
```

or:

```
sed 's|<\([^[:space:]][^[:space:]]*\)/>|<\1></\1>|g' < input_file > output_file
```

Comment: thank you the sed version worked.. I only removed the `[:space:]` check... also I'm sure that the file I need to edit has only the `<name />` or `<name>value</name>` tags...

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
sed -i 's|<\([[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]]*\)/>|<\1></\1>|g' $input_file
```

to change the file in-line (that's what the `-i` is for). Careful: The `-i` is a GNU extension.

To be POSIX compliant and edit the file inline (on any *IX system), use this:

```
echo '/<[[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]]*\/>/g\
s/<\([[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]]*\)\/>/<\1><\/\1>/g
wq' | ed $input_file
```

See the POSIX standard on [sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/sed.html), [ed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/ed.html), and [regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html).

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression to match your tags would be:

```
<(\w+)/>
```

By using the capture group, you could create the new tags like this:

```
<\1></\1>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo '<book/>' | sed 's|<\([^/]*\)/>|<\1></\1>|'
<book></book>
```